# Using React, how do you pass a function from a parent component to a child component and run it in the useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, dependency-injection, use-effect

I'm using React to pass a function from a parent component to a child component and trying to run it in the `useEffect()` hook.

**Parent**

```
function Parent(props) {

  function alertMe() {
    alert('me');
  }

  render (
    <div>
      <Child alertMe={alertMe} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Child**

```
function Child(props) {

  const { alertMe } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    alertMe();
  }, [alertMe]);

  render (
    <div>
      // stuff
    </div>
  );
}
```

If I remove `alertMe` as a dependency in the `useEffect()` of the Child component, it only fires once, but I get a warning:

> React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'alertMe'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

The `alertMe` function is defined once in the Parent component on load, so I don't understand why it would run endlessly in the Child component. It's not changing like state.

How can I add `alertMe` as a `useEffect()` dependency but still *only* run it once?

Comment: remove it from the second argument array of `useEffect`. If you give useEffect an empty array as the second argument it will only run on mount.

Comment: @skellertor Yes, but then I get the warning.

Answer (score 0):

See, your `Parent` re-declares `alertMe` each time it's re-rendered. And since `alertMe` is referentially different `useEffect` in `Child` will detect that and re-run.

Better not fighting with `useEffect`'s dependencies(they are for a reason!). Let's ensure your `alertMe` is referentially the same:

```
function Parent(props) {

  const alertMe = useCallback(() => {
    alert('me');
  });

  render (
    <div>
      <Child alertMe={alertMe} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Think about `useEffect` with dependencies list as about `componentDidUpdate` in hooks' world. Better keep component in sync with props than ignore changes outside.

Comment: How would you pass in additional parameters to alertMe ? e.g.
`<Child alertMe={(index) => alertMe(index)} />`

Comment: answer depends on what these parameters are coming from, if they can be changed later and at what layer they are defined - `Parent` or `Child`